# Angularjs ng-options with an array of key-pair

Tags: angularjs

I'm having below array. I'm trying different ng-options but no use. How to render in Drop down using Angularjs ng-options?

getLanguages: 
[0: Object: Key:"en" Value:"English", 1: Object: Key:"fr" Value:"France"]

```
<select ng-options="language.Object.Value for language in getLanguages track by language.Object.Value"/>

<select data-ng-model="vm.model">
    <option data-ng-repeat="language in getLanguages" value="{{language.Object.Key}}">{{language.Object.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

I got Answer:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="vm.model" >
    <option data-ng-repeat="language in vm.getLanguages()" value="{{language.Key}}">{{language.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post real JavaScript code. `[Object: Key:"en" Value:"English", Object: Key:"fr" Value:"France"]` is not JavaScript. Also post all the relevant code. We have no idea of what vm.getLanguages() actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the answer is a combination of both [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501188/419705) and [Stark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501222/419705)'s answers above.

First you need to make sure your controller is correctly returning the languages, as Stark indicated in his answer.

For example, it should include something like:

```
$scope.languages = [
  { key : "en",
    value : "English" },
  { key : "fr",
    value : "French" }];
```

Then you can populate your `<select>` options using those languages. As David pointed out, the correct syntax would be similar to the following:

```
<select ng-model="model.language"
        ng-options="language.key as language.value for language in languages">
```

What this syntax is saying is "show the 'value' in the drop down and map it to the 'key' for each 'language' in the collection returned by the 'languages' variable in the scope." So the drop down will show "English", "French", etc., and when you select one, it will set the model value to "en", "fr", etc.

Here is a [working Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/W4E55oRlIqmTDt0SmxQA/) showing the above in action.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng-options = "language.Object.Key as language.Object.Value for language in getLanguages()"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10709088)

Comment: @konqi actually, I believe that this does provide an answer to the question, though it could use a bit more information than just a single line of code.

Comment: @Claies I don't think so. Even if the code solves to problem, "try the following" is not an answer because it is a request for a test/additional information/clarification. Therefor it should be a comment. If such a comment would lead to a solution an answer could be derived from it. To qualify as an answer the post should at least contain a short explanation of what is wrong and why the provided solution would work. The accepted answer provides everything this post is missing. Arguably the post could be improved into an answer but it wasn't in the review queue for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller("controllername", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.getLanguages = [
        {"en":"English"},
        {"fr":"French"}
    ];

    $scope.getKey = function(getLanguages) {
        return Object.keys(getLanguages)[0];
    }
}]);
```