# Dropdown value is not binding with associative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an associative array like below which I want to bind with my dropdown:

```
{
        "Item1": [
          {
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": [
              "Egg",
              "burger",
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Item2": [
          {
            "title": "Item2",
            "choices": [
              "Pizza",
              "Rice",
            ]
          }
        ]
     }
```

I am trying to bind dropdown based on this associative array, but the problem is it is displaying as `object object`.

I want to show title in dropdown for each of the item like below:

```
Item1
Item2
```

I have tried to take reference from below SO question but it didn't work out:

[key-value pairs in ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734524/key-value-pairs-in-ng-options)

[Angularjs ng-options with an array of key-pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500864/angularjs-ng-options-with-an-array-of-key-pair)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.item=
    {
        "Item1": [
          {
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": [
              "Egg",
              "burger",
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Item2": [
          {
            "title": "Item2",
            "choices": [
              "Pizza",
              "Rice",
            ]
          }
        ]
     }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
     <select ng-model="myItem.title" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in item">
           <option value="">Select Items</option>
     </select>
</ul>
```

Comment: do your item details (the Object with title, choices) need to be wrapped in array? would be easier to parse without that array wrapper.

Comment: @jdubjdub actually I am having various types of items like french,Italian,chineses in which each of this items will have some choices I.e is I have this items as associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like to this:

```
   ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in item">
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.item=
    {
        "Item1": [
          {
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": [
              "Egg",
              "burger",
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Item2": [
          {
            "title": "Item2",
            "choices": [
              "Pizza",
              "Rice",
            ]
          }
        ]
     }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
     <select ng-model="myItem.title" ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in item">
           <option value="">Select Items</option>
     </select>
     
     {{myItem.title}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Why value[0]?Wont this will always select only first item of my associative array??

Comment: It is unclear that what is the option value? see updated answer.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Can you please explain me about ng-options for this associative array :)

Comment: of course. just i don't konw what do you want have for `ng-model`? value is vague for me.

Comment: I only want to have title i.e item1 not whole object in my ng-model

Comment: so you should try this `value[0].title as key ...`

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)